# Templated function in templated class

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

With

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    template <int x>
    void bar () {}
};
```

the following compiles:

```
void fooBar ()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    f.bar<1>();
}
```

but the following does not (with "error: expected primary-expression before ')' token" in gcc 5.4.0 with -std=c++14).

```
template <typename T>
void fooBar ()
{
    Foo<T> f;
    f.bar<1>();
}
```

If I try to explicitly call the second version, with e.g.

```
fooBar<int>();
```

then gcc additionally complains about

```
"invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and 'int' to binary 'operator<'".
```

Is there any reason why the second version is invalid? Why is gcc treating the '<' as an operator rather than the beginning of a template parameter list?

Comment: what is the function `foo<>();`? Where does it exist?

Comment: @alhadhrami Sorry - should have read fooBar. Corrected in edit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the templated function, the compiler doesn't know exactly what `Foo<T>` will be (there could be specializations of `Foo`), so it it has to assume that `f.bar` is a member variable and parse the code as

```
f.bar < 1
```

and then it cannot continue.

You can help the compiler by telling it that `bar` is a template

```
f.template bar<1>();
```

Comment: This works - and I've never seen this syntax before. I would never have thought of trying this. Thank you!